# Buggy Javascript Function Complains Missing For Loop ")"

Tags: javascript

The following is my simple function to create a range array between two numbers. The problem is that console keeps complaining that for loop has a missing bracket ")" but I can plainly see that it is not missing. Please help!

```
function range(start, end){
    var len = end - start;
    for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++){
        var arr[i] = x + i;
    }
    return arr[];
}
console.log(range(1, 10));
console.log(arr.length);
```

Here is the output:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control (line 3)
```

Edit

```
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++){
```

was

```
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++;){
```

Comment: It's probably expecting a `)` _before_ the semi-colon you've put after `i++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three errors. I cannot fix undeclared 'x', which is either in outter scope (global) or this is an error that you have to fix with your own logic.

```
function range(start, end){
    var arr = []; //declare your array
    var len = end - start;
    for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++){
        arr[i] = x + i; //here x is undeclared, single array indices cannot be declared this way
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(range(1, 10));
console.log(arr.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                            remove
                             ↓
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++;)
```

Remove the final semicolon:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++)
```

Your code has other issues, but this answers the question asked.  I suggest you pull out a guide on JavaScript and correct your syntax throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put a semi-colon (;) after the last statment in the for loop. Remove it.

It's very unlikely that something like a for loop is buggy in JavaScript, in a language that is usef by millions every day.